# Accessing the value of other sliders from within a ValueChangingFcn

Tags: matlab, callback, slider, matlab-gui

I have multiple sliders inside a figure, and I would like to publish their values (using the robotics toolbox) when one of them changes. I'm unable to access the value of more than one slider - an attempt to access the slider values gives me the following error in the `sliderMoving` function:

```
Undefined variable "event1" or class "event1.Value".
```

The code is as follows:

```
function sliderchanging

%rosinit('129.78.214.177');
first_val = 0;
euler_v = rossubscriber('/Euler_values');
slider_v = rospublisher('/Slider_values', 'std_msgs/Float64MultiArray');
slidermsg = rosmessage(slider_v); 

eulermsg = rostopic('echo', '/Euler_values');
ypr = eulermsg.Data;
y = ypr(1);
p = ypr(2);
r = ypr(3);

fig = uifigure;
sld = uislider(fig,'Position',[20 50 260 20],'ValueChangingFcn',@(sld,event) sliderMoving(event, slidermsg, slider_v, y, p, r));
sld1 = uislider(fig,'Position',[20 80 260 20],'ValueChangingFcn',@(sld1,event1) sliderMoving(event1, slidermsg, slider_v, y, p, r));

if first_val == 0
   send(slider_v, eulermsg); 
end
sld.Limits = [y-2 y+2];
sld.Value = y;
sld.Position = [20 50 260 20];
sld1.Limits = [p-2 p+2];
sld1.Value = p;
sld1.Position = [20 80 260 20];
end

function sliderMoving(event, slidermsg, slider_v, y, p, r)
first_val = 1;

disp(event.Value)
disp(event1.Value)
slidermsg.Data = [event.Value, p, r];
send(slider_v, slidermsg)
end
```

What is wrong with this code? How can I access the values of all available sliders from within the `sliderMoving` callback?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Instead of asking that, *specify the problem*. There's a very minimal description of what you're attempting to do, and a lot of code, but no specifics as to where you're stuck with this code. What line does the error occur? What did you already try to solve the error?

Comment: @Adriaan I've updated the question. Basically, I am unable to create multiple sliders and need help in doing so

Comment: That question is too broad... and your error message clearly states `event1` is undefined, when used in the line `disp(event1.Value)`... What do you expect `event1` to be here? You haven't defined it anywhere in the code...

Comment: @Wolfie Well, it seemed to be intuitive to create an event on varying the slider.. as  defined in the sliderchanging function.

Comment: Yes, the `event` variable is created by the callback, and is an input to the function. `event1` is something which is never defined... The callback function just knows there's a single event, regardless what you called it when you defined the callback. Variable names don't carry across functions like that, the variable name within a function should correspond to the input name, not a name elsewhere in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because the `sliderMoving` function does not know the name of the variable in the calling workspace. In other words,

```
function out = func(in)
  % do something with in
end
```

won't behave differently if we call it like `func(in1)` or `func(in2)`.

In your case, the event will always be known **inside** the callback as `event`.

If you want different behavior based on which slider was used, you should decide based on the first two inputs to the callback ([commonly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html): `src` and `eventData`), or via some additional input parameter (as you already do). If you need to access the value of the other slider, you can do this using `event.Source.Parent.otherSld`.

You should also note that the statement `first_val = 1;` that is found inside the callback has no effect on the value outside the callback. You should read about [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

I think this is what you meant to do:

```
function sliderchanging
...
fig = uifigure;
...

  function sliderMoving(...)

  end
end
```

Comment: You could also pass additional arguments in the callback creation (and corresponding function inputs) which identify the user-defined slider "number"

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks, I mentioned this too now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. @Wolfie Thanks, that worked

Comment: @Dev-iL Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I got confused there and made that blundermistake

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says event1 is not a variable or class. You can't copy the slider code and put a 1 after every entry.

I suggest you look at the MATLAB documentation on `events`. You will have to use  `event`
in both slider definitions and either use a different callback for each slider or if you use the same call back then you will need to find someway of identifying which slider triggered the callback.